# PHP ini parsing error

Tags: php, ini

I am getting ini Parsing Error for the following [ini file](http://pastebin.com/f706QMPV):

```
[photo]
price = 5.00

[shipping]
South Africa[value] = 50.00
South Africa[incremental] = 100

Pakistan[value] = 120.00
Pakistan[incremental] = 100

[discount]
min[quantity] = 50
min[value] = 5

max[quantity] = 150
max[value] = 10

[admin]
email = xxxx@gmail.com
name = Admin
subject = Your order with xxx
```

The error comes on Line #5

It's quite weird. The same file works fine on my own machine but not on remote server

Comment: Would this be parsed into an array?

Comment: try quoting the floats, e.g. `"50.00"` instead of `50.00`

Comment: @Pekka yes it would be in Array form

Comment: @scibuff I give it a try, it works fine on my local machine

Comment: @scibuff putting it quotes did not make any difference. Same error

Comment: how about if you remove that line ... does it go through or does it crash on some other line?

Comment: oh, try to quote the array keys!, ie instead of `South Africa[value]` do `South Africa["value"]`

Comment: This is most likely a difference in the `parse_ini_file` implementations on the different servers.

Comment: @Vytautas PHP has bult-in ini parser

Comment: @scibuff I just used PHP example and it did not work.  [third_section]
phpversion["a"] = "5.0"
phpversion["b"] = "5.1"
phpversion["c"] = "5.2"
phpversion["d"] = "5.3"

Comment: I have tested with `parse_ini_file()` works fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any particular reason you can't do something like

```
$ini = array();

$ini["photo"]["price"] = 5.00;

$ini["shipping"]["South Africa"]["value"] = 50.00;
$ini["shipping"]["South Africa"]["incremental"] = 100;
```

Comment: The Ini file will be used by someone who does not know programming, way easier than setting array in PHP file. The thing is, it works fine on my local machine but not remote. Is there any version issue or something else

Comment: The value like **South Africa[value]* is creating problem, seems its not accepting nested values

Comment: Ok its confirmed, its not parsing nested values,I don't get why its like that.

Comment: what php version does the server have?

Comment: I rather made it as a PHP array like you mentioned. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to PHP5.3.1 to parse nested variables' values.

We've just confirmed the same issue on one of our LAMP servers, running PHP 5.2.17 as well.

The same code works on a different server running PHP5.3.8